# Error occurred when creating the ssh key (ssh-keygen returned 1)

Tags: vagrant

```
vagrant init precise32
vagrant up
```

This normally works, i've not changed anything but now every time I try run vagrant it gives me

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Less insecure SSH key not found, generating key
Error occurred when creating the ssh key (ssh-keygen returned 1)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you change permissions of `~/.ssh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by the new `vagrant-rekey-ssh` plugin.

If you do `vagrant up --debug` and examine the ouput, you will see that the following causes your command to fail:

```
 Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin/ssh-keygen.EXE", "-f", "C:
/Users/Nik/.vagrant.d/less_insecure_private_key", "-N", ""]
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stderr: ssh-keygen.EXE": option requires an argument -- N
```

A simple fix for this problem is to manually generate a private key.
To do so simply do: `ssh-keygen -f ~/.vagrant.d/less_insecure_private_key`

Comment: I found out that the plugin was the cause of my problems and removed it however thank you for the insight :)

Comment: No problem :) I had the same issue hence I wanted to know more about it

Comment: found the same issue. your simple fix with a little tweak in windows worked great: ssh-keygen -f ~/.vagrant.d/less_insecure_private_key